# Problems with parsing JSON feed in app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json

The following JSON feed contains orders.

How can I retrieve each order, when it doesn't contain a key (can´t use objectForKey)? Between the opening bracket and the first curly bracket there is no key.

```
[ <-----
    { <-----
        "person": {
            "address": "My road",
            "city": "My City",
            "name": "My Name",
        },
        "orderDate": "30.05.2012 10:27",
        "orderId": 10001,
        "orderlines": [
            {
                "unit": {
                    "unitId": "RA005",
                    "name": "My Unit name",
                },
                "id": 10007,
                "deliveryInfo": {
                    "count": 1,
                    "date": "30.05.2012",
                    "format": "MY_FORMAT",
                },
                "sum": 0,
                "details": "Testing",
                "priority": 3,
            }
        ],
        "received": true,
        "status": "REGISTERED",
        "sumPrice": 0
    },
    {
        "person": {
            "address": "My road 2",
            "city": "My City 2",
            "name": "My Name 2",
        },
        "orderDate": "30.04.2012 10:27",
        "orderId": 10002,
        "orderlines": [
            {
                "unit": {
                    "unitId": "RA006",
                    "name": "My Unit name 2",
                },
                "id": 10008,
                "deliveryInfo": {
                    "count": 2,
                    "date": "01.06.2012",
                    "format": "MY_FORMAT",
                },
                "sum": 0,
                "details": "Testing",
                "priority": 2,
            }
        ],
        "received": true,
        "status": "REGISTERED",
        "sumPrice": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: That's an array of items. You can use `objectAtIndex:` to retrieve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whenever you see [] (square brackets), it represents array. so use object at index to return the at indexes. one approach is to pass the object into array like

```
NSMutableArray *arr = (NSMutableArray*) jsonData;
```

Answer (score 1):

since the root of your json is an array,

```
NSError *e = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

if (!jsonArray) {
  NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
} else {
   for(NSDictionary *item in jsonArray) {
      NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
   }
}
```